# Load different ascx's in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, treeview

On my aspx page I have on the left hand side TreeView for each of every node in the TreeView I want to load a different ascx which going to change only the right hand side of the page.

Thats how my aspx.vb look like:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GenerateDataSets()
        GenerateLabels()
        GenerateLinks()
        GenerateControls()
        GenerateOther()
    End If

End Sub
```

When it's getting to GenerateLinks()

```
 Protected Sub GenerateLinks()
        Dim subTreeStatisticalReport As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("StatisticalReport")
        Dim subTreeIncidentComparisons As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentComparisons")
        Dim subTreeGeographicLocations As RadTreeNode = rtvReports.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("GeographicLocations")

        Dim statTimeOfDayNode As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("TimeofDay")
        Dim statTrendsNode As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Trends")
        Dim statTopSevenIncidents As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Top7Incidents")
        Dim statIncidentPerCategory As RadTreeNode = subTreeStatisticalReport.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentsPerCategory")
        Dim compIncidentLoss As RadTreeNode = subTreeIncidentComparisons.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("IncidentLoss")
        Dim GeoMaps As RadTreeNode = subTreeGeographicLocations.Nodes.FindNodeByValue("Maps")




        statTimeOfDayNode.NavigateUrl = Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Reports/Reports.aspx?SessionID=" + m_SessionID + "&qrptTOD=tod")
End Sub
```

Now if the user is going to click on the Time Of Day Node it's going to load the same page again but different ascx.

```
Private Sub RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()
        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("SessionID")) Then
                m_SessionID = Request.QueryString("SessionID")
                m_qrptTOD = Request.QueryString("qrptTOD")
            ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("SessionID")) Then
                m_SessionID = Session("SessionID")
            End If

            If m_qrptTOD = "tod" Then
                Page.LoadControl("/Controls/Reports/rptTimeOfDay.ascx")
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

When it's getting here:

```
 If m_qrptTOD = "tod" Then
                Page.LoadControl("/Controls/Reports/rptTimeOfDay.ascx")
            End If
```

the ascx page is not loading for some reason!!
What I'm doing wrong?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load user control in the Page Load event. It is too LATE. Read more about [Asp.Net Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx). Relevant part quoted below.

> Page Event Init: Raised after all controls have been initialized and
>   any skin settings have been applied. The Init event of individual
>   controls occurs before the Init event of the page. Use this event to
>   read or initialize control properties.

You need to load your control before this event.

Instead of Page.LoadControl("UserControlPath"), you can control visibility of your ascx files. Try following code.

```
If m_qrptTOD = "tod" Then
       ascxRptTimeOfDay.Visible = False
End If
```

Note that your rptTimeOfDay.ascx UserControl will always be loaded in this approach, you only change its visibility. But, in Asp.NET , no html code will be sent to client if user control is not visible.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my Master Page I have Left Hand Side and Right Hand side....When the user clicked on the Node I'm reloading the same page again and on page load I'm reading what's in the QueryString if it's equal to my condition I'm doing something like that  Me.Master.FindControl("RightContent").Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(("/Controls/Reports/rptTimeOfDay.ascx")))    Now the ascx been load but It's not coming on top of the last ascx it's shown below it. What should I do?